# Why am I getting an IsolatedStorageException thrown the second time I am writing to the same file?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my unit tests, I am using the following code to open a stream and write to it:

```
IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
stream = m_store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Create);
...
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();
stream.Dispose();
store.Dispose()
```

The first time it succeeds, but the second time it fails with the following log output:
Additional information: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

The FileMode.Create enum constant is defined as:

*Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate.*

so it appears this is the correct constant.

I have found a few similar questions on stackoverflow such as
[IsolatedStorageFileStream exception is throw when file is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512165/isolatedstoragefilestream-exception-is-throw-when-file-is-opened)

but they didn't help. As suggested somewhere on the net (can't find the link now), I tried deleting the file first if it existed, contrary to the enum comments, like below, but didn't help either:

```
if (store.FileExists(filename))
{
   store.DeleteFile(filename);
}
```

QUESTION: What I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should *really* use a `using` statement instead of explicitly calling `Close` or `Dispose` - otherwise if there's an exception, you *won't* have closed the stream.

Secondly, I suspect the problem is that you haven't disposed of the store itself. Try this:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var stream = store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not it unfortunately... The above code is a bit of an oversimplification. The local variables are actually data members in a class and I am actually doing the closing in a member function, and also disposing the store as well in that function. I have also added log statements so I am certain that this function is being called... I can't use a using because the opening and writing to stream is done outside of the class I am implementing...

Comment: @swinefeaster: It's hard to tell what's wrong with your real code if you post different code which has different problems. I appreciate that genuine short-but-complete programs are somewhat difficult to post for a phone app, but you could post a short but complete *section* of a program.

Comment: Ok my bad... sorry for wasting your time. I was closing the output stream correctly, but not the input stream (for reading the file). This was causing the problem. But anyways, good pointers on the using keyword!

Answer (score 0):

You put the reference to the Iso-store in the local variable **store** but later you use a member(?) variable **m_store** to create the stream. 
Is that just a typo in this question or is that the actual code that you are executing?

Comment: it is a typo... i will post a better example of the code later today